# What does "primary calendar" mean?

Tags: fixed, income

I was reading the 2013 research rankings article on Institutional Investor and came across the following quote: "We do not expect spread widening in most markets, and we expect the primary calendar to remain strong."  The quote is in relation to fixed income markets.

What does "primary calendar" here mean?

Answer (score 1):

"Primary calendar" in this context most likely means the schedule of emissions on the primary market.

If the primary calendar is strong, there are lots of emissions both in number and size.